P tree Table not expanding in HTML CSS
My HTML
 <p-treeTable *ngIf="treeNode?.length > 0" [value]="treeNode" dynamic="true" (onLazyLoad)="editNodeExpand($event) "
             (onNodeExpand)="editNodeExpand($event) " >
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <tr>
                <th>Crop Name</th>
                <th>CCE Planned</th>
                <th>CCE Completed </th>
                <th>State Approved </th>
                <th>Central Approved </th>
                <th>Average Yield (Kg/Ha) </th>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData">
              <tr class="addColor" [ttRow]="rowNode">
                <td>
                  <!-- {{rowNode | json}} -->
                  <p-treeTableToggler   *ngIf="treeNode?.length > 0" [rowNode]="rowNode"></p-treeTableToggler>
                  {{rowNode?.node?.label}}
                </td>
                <td>{{rowNode?.node?.plannedCCE}}</td>
                <td>{{rowNode?.node?.completedCCECount}}</td>
                <td>{{rowNode?.node?.totalStateApproval}}</td>
                <td>{{rowNode?.node?.totalCentralApproval}}</td>
                <td>{{rowNode?.node?.averageYield}}</td>
  
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            
          </p-treeTable>
  
  

I'm trying to expand my p tree table but it is only working with two clicks. at first it is calling and second click is expanded the p tree table

Please post the generated HTML in order to create a [mre]

generated HTML as in ? the output or the js function
